# Повторять чейн анимацию с animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, анимация

К примеру у меня идет чейн анимация через 'animation-delay'. для 15ти блоков. Нужно чтобы после проигрывания последней анимации запускать весь чейн заново. Это можно как-то через js сделать?

```js
$.fn.extend({
    animateCss: function (animationName) {
        var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
        this.addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
        });
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".show1").animateCss('fadeIn');
  $(".show2").css('animation-delay', '.5s');

  $(".show2").animateCss('fadeIn');
  $(".show2").css('animation-delay', '1s');

});
```

```html
<link href="http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="show1">
  Show1
</div>

<div class="show2">
  Show2
</div>
```

Comment: Если вам нужно большая точность этого самого "сразу", то проблема в том, что часы в css и js идут по-разному: https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/ypyzuas6/ (взят запас в 4 "шага", чтобы все блоки успели проанимироваться; при запасе в 1 шаг, который должен был быть, если часы были синхронны, на практике несколько последних блоков "подвисает")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У нас есть уже обработчик события в конце анимации, нужно просто передать в него функцию, которая будет запускать заново анимацию:

```
animateCss: function(animationName, functionAtEnd) {
...
}
```

Объект, анимирующийся последним передаст функцию, которая задает параметры анимации:

```
function animationSetup() {
    $(".show1").animateCss('fadeIn');
    ....
    $(".show15").animateCss('fadeIn',animationSetup);
}
```

Единственное, если мы сразу зададим класс с анимацией, браузер будет считать, что класс и не убирался, поэтому я запускаю функцию через `setTimeout` с минимальным интервалом:

```
this.addClass('animated ' + animationName).on(animationEnd, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
    setTimeout(functionAtEnd,10)
})
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
$.fn.extend({
  animateCss: function(animationName, functionAtEnd) {
    var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
    this.addClass('animated ' + animationName).on(animationEnd, function() {
      $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
      setTimeout(functionAtEnd,10)
    })
    
  }
});

function animationSetup() {
  $(".show1").animateCss('fadeIn');
  $(".show2").css('animation-delay', '.5s');

  $(".show2").animateCss('fadeIn');
  $(".show2").css('animation-delay', '1s');

  $(".show3").animateCss('fadeIn',animationSetup);
  $(".show3").css('animation-delay', '2s');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  animationSetup()
});
```

```html
<link href="http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="show1">
  Show1
</div>
<div class="show2">
  Show2
</div>
<div class="show3">
  Show3
</div>
```